# Open source SSO service

Tags: networking, authentication

My company's DevOps team has some available tools hosted on different servers in the intranet. We would like to intercept the traffic coming to these IPs and put an authorization system which lets some users connect to some IPs. We prefer the app to be open source or free. For an example keycloak seems like it provides our needs but I tried it and encountered some technical issues. So alternatives are appreciated.